# Clip HTML Tab Elements/Buttons Using CSS on resizing

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML/CSS. I am trying to create a tabs bar with buttons:

```css
#TabsBar {
 padding: 0px 12px; /*Like TopBanner*/
 height: 40px; /*TopBanner height*/
 width: calc(100% - 24px); /* to compensate for the padding*/
 background-color: blue;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.Tabs {
 background-color: transparent;
 border: hidden;
 font-size: 120%;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0px 20px;
}

.HeightInherit {
 height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div id="TabsBar">
  <button type="button" class="Tabs HeightInherit">Tab1</button>
  <button type="button" class="Tabs HeightInherit">Tab2</button>
  <button type="button" class="Tabs HeightInherit">Tab3</button>
</div>
```

The problem is when I resize the screen, the elements get hidden once the screen border touched them. I need the button to still show even if the screen width is reduced and only the part off-screen gets clipped (i.e. partial clipping).

I hope the question is clear enough.

Comment: I changed the width for #TabsBar to 200%, it did the trick.... but I still need a straight answer for this issue, not a workaround.

Comment: no need to specify a width at all, keep it auto

Comment: also add `white-space:nowrap` it will fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the fixed height and no overflow showing. You can put a min-width on #TabsBar to prevent this (simplest but not as flexible)

```
#TabsBar {
    padding: 0px 12px; /*Like TopBanner*/
    height: 40px; /*TopBanner height*/
    width: calc(100% - 24px); /* to compensate for the padding*/
    background-color: blue;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

If I were doing it, I would still get rid of the overflow-hidden but use white-space: nowrap to keep everything in a single line

```
#TabsBar {
    padding: 0px 12px; /*Like TopBanner*/
    height: 40px; /*TopBanner height*/
    width: calc(100% - 24px); /* to compensate for the padding*/
    background-color: blue;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: `The issue is with the fixed height` ... `you can put min-width` ??

Comment: min-height and min-width can be used and this is typically where fixed number of pixels appear (as opposed to width and height being percentages to be responsive)

Comment: i know what both means ;) but what is the logic or your statement ? ... you have issue with fixed height so you have to use min-width ?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough space to display all the tabs after resizing the screen under a certain width. The right way to respond to this is by using media queries and adjust your tabs CSS. How exactly - it's your choice. But usually this is a screen size of a mobile device and changing the flow from horizontal to vertical is the way to go. Take a look at the end of the CSS where the media querie is defined and adjust it to your needs.

```css
#TabsBar {
 padding: 0px 12px; /*Like TopBanner*/
 height: 40px; /*TopBanner height*/
 width: calc(100% - 24px); /* to compensate for the padding*/
 background-color: blue;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.Tabs {
 background-color: transparent;
 border: hidden;
 font-size: 120%;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0px 20px;
}

.HeightInherit {
 height: inherit;
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
  .Tabs { 
    display: block; 
    width: 100%;
    }
   #TabsBar {
     height: auto;
   }
}
```

```html
<div id="TabsBar">
  <button type="button" class="Tabs HeightInherit">Tab1</button>
  <button type="button" class="Tabs HeightInherit">Tab2</button>
  <button type="button" class="Tabs HeightInherit">Tab3</button>
</div>
```